# How to compare directed graphs in Networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have two directed Networkx graphs with equal number of nodes and edges.

[image]
How to compare the structure of these two different graphs in Networkx? Node names don't matter. I tried to use Networkx `DiGraph.order()`, `DiGraph.degree()` etc. from [Information about graph structure](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/classes.digraph.html) but all parameters of my graphs are equal.

And generally how to compare structures of more than 2 graphs and find only graphs with unique structure. Is there special function for this in Networkx?

Comment: Maybe your are looking for isomorphism?  Try http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic

Comment: Thanks @Aric ! This is what I need! And do you know how to compare structures of more than 2 graphs and find only graphs with unique structure? Is there special function for this in Networkx?

Answer (score 4):

To determine if two graphs are isomorphic you can use the function `is_isomorphic()`. Unfortunately there is no function to compare more than 2 graphs. But you can compare all possible graph combinations and build the graph `iso_graph` from combinations which are isomorphic. To find all isomorphic graph groups you can use the function `connected_components()` or `find_cliques()` with `iso_graph`:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

G1 = nx.path_graph(4)
G2 = nx.path_graph(4)
G3 = nx.path_graph(4)
G4 = nx.path_graph(5)
G5 = nx.path_graph(5)
G6 = nx.path_graph(5)

graphs = {G1: 'G1', G2: 'G2', G3: 'G3', G4: 'G4', G5: 'G5', G6: 'G6'}
iso_pairs = {(graphs[g1], graphs[g2]) for g1, g2 in combinations(graphs, 2) if nx.is_isomorphic(g1, g2)}
# {('G1', 'G3'), ('G5', 'G6'), ('G4', 'G6'), ('G1', 'G2'), ('G4', 'G5'), ('G2', 'G3')}

iso_graph = nx.from_edgelist(iso_pairs) 
for c in nx.connected_components(iso_graph):
    print(c)
# {'G1', 'G3', 'G2'}
# {'G5', 'G6', 'G4'}

%matplotlib inline # jupyter notebook
nx.draw(iso_graph, with_labels=True)
```

[image: iso_graph]

Answer (score 0):

The most common function for measuring graph similarity is the "edit distance".

The graph edit distance is the number of edge/node changes needed to make two graphs isomorphic.

Networkx  several (optimized) versions:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/similarity.html